# how to mark selectable property false without rendering the full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want to mark the selectable property for fullcalendar to be set to false on change of particular view.

Currently its not working.
Below is the code I have added.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('option', 'selectable', false);          
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'timeLineMonthly');
```

Where timeLineMonthly is the view defined for fullcalendar.

I don't want to render fullcalendar again. I just want to fire the changeView event and set the selectable option to false.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by setting the [selectable](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectable/) property in the [View-Specific Options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/).

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    views: {
        week: {
            selectable: false
        },
        timeLineMonthly: {
            selectable: true
        }
    }
});
```