# dayGridMonth unselectable fullcalendar

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm new in Laravel and I use the `fullcalendar`. I want the `dayGridMonth` View to be unselectable BUT the other views like `timeGridWeek`, `timeGridDay` will be selectable. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Share your code or follow this link (https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-ajax-full-calendar-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

For now, What I can think of, is to use [View-Specific options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options).

Use Selectable in all views with true or false related to that view and try if it works for you.

You may [check this question for an Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358802/how-to-mark-selectable-property-false-without-rendering-the-full-calendar)

It might look like the following:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  views: {
    dayGrid: {
      selectable: false
    },
    timeGrid: {
      selectable: true
    },
    week: {
      selectable: true
    },
    day: {
      selectable: true
    }
  }
});
```